# Function that takes parts of text from a file and writes it into seperate files in Python

Tags: python, list

I would like to know how to create a function that will split a file containing some number of paragraphs into separate output files, one paragraph per file. Each file should be named fileN.txt, N is the number of the paragraph.

```
    def para_split(input_file):
        input_file = open(input_file, "r")
        para_whole = input_file.readlines()

        para1 = para_whole[0:17]
        para2 = para_whole[17:34]
        para3 = para_whole[34:51]
        para4 = para_whole[51:68]
        input_file.close()
```

Comment: Just FYI: There's a unix tool called `split` that does exactly what you want.

Comment: @L3viathan But how would I use it in this case?

Comment: You could identify what separates a paragraph from another (a point or an empty line for example), count everytime when that happens and write in different files when this count reaches certain values.

Comment: @Kamejoin could you give me an example in code format?

Comment: Of course, wait for my answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15934386/3681882, http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66063-read-a-text-file-by-paragraph/#c1

Comment: @Kamejoin Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, if your file is like:

```
... finishing this paragraph.

Starting this paragraph...
```

That means that every paragraph is separated from eachother by an empty line. So, try this:

```
def para_split(input_file):
    input_file = open(input_file, "r")
    empty_lines = 0
    amount_of_files = 5
    files = []

    for i in range(amount_of_files):
         output_file = open('file'+str(i)+'.txt','w')
         files.append(output_file)

    for line in input_file:
        if empty_lines < 10:
             files[0].write(line)
        elif 10 <= empty_lines < 15:
             files[1].write(line)
         .
         .
         .
        elif 50 <= empty_lines < 60:
             files[4].write(line)

        if line == '\n':
            empty_lines += 1

    for file in files:
        file.close()
```

Check if that works, I can't do it on this computer.

Comment: Awesome, one question how do I make the output be "file0.txt"

Comment: With the first `for` iteration. It gives the name to every file according to the values of **i**.

Comment: how would I get the numbering of the files to start at 1 and end at 4. Your very helpful.

Comment: In the first `for` change `str(i)` with `str(i+1)` and reduce `amount_of_files` to 4.

Comment: Everything works perfectly!!! Life saver!!

Comment: Be careful though, it has an error, empty_lines should get += 1 only when we get an empty line. I'm gonna edit it, but if already is enough thats awesome.

Comment: '\n' stand for 'next line'. Each line of every file ends with this symbol. Since an empty line is also a line, it must have at least this symbol in it. Generally '\n' is invisible, but is crucial in python.

Comment: after adding your edit, the paragraphs all ended up in the first file and not split apart. :(

Comment: lol then go back to the first version. I think you want to separate by number of lines instead of number of paragraphs.